# Why is RKelly being sent to Prison and not my case?

Tags: criminal-law, california

I live in CA and I was sexually assaulted by my sister father around 1985 or 1986.

I went to the police and made a report regarding my sister father sexually assaulting me without using a condom I was around 11 or 12 years this was around 1985 or 1986. He wouldn't allow me to go to the police or a doctor I was a little girl and I was afraid of him and to speak out. I went to the police and they say the statute of limitations is up and it's too late. How could I file if I did not know?

Answer (score 3):

### Unfortunately, the police are correct

The limit on filing a civil claim (a lawsuit where you seek monetary compensation) is before you turn [40](https://www.taylorring.com/practice-areas/sexual-abuse-sexual-assault/time-limits-to-file-lawsuits/). If you were 11 in 1985 then it is too late to sue your assaulter.

For criminal prosecution, the [law](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/billNavClient.xhtml?bill_id=201520160SB813) was changed in 2016. Prior to the change, the limitation was the same as for civil cases. After the change, there is no limit but only if the offence was committed on or after 1 January 2017.

Assuming that your reference to Kelly is to [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._Kelly#Alleged_sexual_abuse_of_minors) - the alleged offences were committed in the 1990s and the prosecutions are under Illinois, Minnesota and Federal law (the Federal crimes alleged are not the sexual assault of a minor). Each state has it's own rules.

Comment: Just wicked its sick im in CA and he still gets to have sex and live as a rapist smh

Comment: Yes, the laws in those states are stricter in CA thats not the case.

Comment: I want to file a lawsuit against my state than for failing to protect a child that was sexually assaulted with no condom by rapist whom is still out there having sex also with other minors.